# Translating mouse position to world position yields constant result

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a topdown 3d shooter. I want to find the position of the mouse in the world so I can shoot a bullet from the player's position towards the mouse position on mouse click. So to begin with I'm trying to get the positions of both objects:

```
void Update()
        {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
Debug.Log(
      "Player position = " + transform.position + 
    "; Mouse position = " + Input.mousePosition + 
    "; Mouse position in world = " + mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        }
```

These are the results:

**Clicking right on top of the player** 
Player position = (0.0, 0.5, 0.0); 
Mouse position = (968.3, 543.1, 0.0);
Mouse position in world = (0.0, 25.0, 0.0)

**Above the player** 
Player position = (0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
Mouse position = (957.9, 686.7, 0.0);
Mouse position in world = (0.0, 25.0, 0.0)

**Right of the player** 
Player position = (0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
Mouse position = (1114.0, 557.7, 0.0);
Mouse position in world = (0.0, 25.0, 0.0)

**Below the player** 
Player position = (0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
Mouse position = (962.1, 414.1, 0.0);
Mouse position in world = (0.0, 25.0, 0.0)

**Left of the player** 
Player position = (0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
Mouse position = (822.7, 557.7, 0.0);
Mouse position in world = (0.0, 25.0, 0.0)

So looks like the translation to world coordinates always yields the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation to world coordinates will always yield the same result when you give it no depth. It is simply returning the camera position. To resolve this, simply store the mouse position in a temporary `Vector3` and assign some z for depth. It could look something like:

```
Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = -mainCamera.transform.position.z)

mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
```

To read more about it, the [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) docs specify:

> The z position is in world units from the camera.

As Unity implicitly converts a `Vector2` to `Vector3`, the z component you have passed in will always be 0.